# sed found lines with set articles (a, an, the)

Tags: sed

I should find lines with articles i set by myself. Search among first 10 lines.

```
sed -n '/the/p' file.txt | sed -n '/ a /p' file.txt
```

will show only output from the last command. Also

```
sed -n '1,10 /the/p' file
```

or

```
sed -n 1,10p '/the/p' file
```

dont work, i found usage of range only with patterns like

```
[range]/s/pattern/pattern/p
```

How can i combine several conditions and range of lines?

Example of file:

```
For the first time since early February
the top three films at the weekend 
box office were all new releases
and leading the way was
Fox's Bohemian Rhapsody
with a $50 million
chart-topping performance
well above expectations.
That said, the weekend isn't all about
new releases as the holdovers
```

Output should be:

```
 For the first time since early February
 the top three films at the weekend
 and leading the way was
 with a $50 million
 That said, the weekend isn't all about
 new releases as the holdovers
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- To get lines containing `the`

  ```
  sed -n '1,10{/\<the\>/p}' file
  ```
- To get lines containing `the` or `a` or `an`

  ```
  sed -n '1,10{/\<\(the\|a\|an\)\>/p}' file
  ```

Comment: Thanks, it work with one condition. Do you know how to search lines, for example, with 'the' or 'a' articles?

Comment: You'd better add some boundaries otherwise `a` doesn't only look for article `a` necessarily.